How to add fontFamily, fontSize, alignment to the toolbar in react-native-ckeditor5 (React Native)
I'm trying to add FontFamily,FontSize,Alignment. But it doesn't work in the toolbar of react-native-ckeditor5 I tried installing @ckeditor/ckeditor5-font and added it as a plugin in editorConfig, but it still doesn't work. What should I do to add FontFamily,FontSize,Alignment to the toolbar Or have other suggestions or another method Thanks.
import { Font } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font';

<CKEditor5
  initialData={inputValue}
  onChange={handleTextChange}
  editorConfig={{
    config: [Font],
    fontFamily: {
      options: [
        'default',
        'Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif',
        'Ubuntu Mono, Courier New, Courier, monospace',
      ],
    },
    toolbar: [
      'heading',
      'bulletedList',
      'numberedList',
      'fontFamily',
      '|',
      'alignment:left',
      'alignment:right',
      'alignment:center',
      'alignment:justify',
      '|',
      'undo',
      'redo',
    ],
  }}
  colors={colors}
  toolbarBorderSize="0px"
  editorFocusBorderSize="0px"
/>

